# Tor for Chromebook

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, chrome-os

I am thinking of getting a Chromebook in the not so distant future. However, I want to be able to use Tor on it. However, since, at least that is my perception, everything goes through Google, will Tor then be available on a Chromebook?

Comment: Tor is not supported on Chrome OS.
You might be able to run it if you install ubuntu on it, but keep in mind that the browserbundle is not for ARM architecture, you you cannot use tor browser bundle, but you can install tor on ubuntu on it and set up transparent proxying.

Comment: After posting I found the older question. However, it hadn't been accessed in over a year, and I don't know if you can "bump" here.

Answer (score 1):

TOR is not available for Chrome. Though it is not recommended but you can choose out of various options if you have to.

1. Use [Tor2Web](https://tor2web.org/) to access all the TOR Network Hidden Services ( aka .onion sites ) without TOR.
2. Route all the data through a proxy server using [OrBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android) and *Proxy Serve*r apps on Android Phones.

Also, if you have a Chromebook with the Play Store on it, like the Asus Chromebook Flip, you can run Orbot and Orfox independently of the Chrome browser, and therefore access Tor!